# Dealing with slow callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When getting data from a text file, it seems to take a while. With the first console.log the result is undefined, after waiting some time and then running console.log the data shows.

```
var msg;
$.get("./whazzup.txt", function(text) {
  msg = text;
});
console.log(msg);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(msg); }, 3000);
```

How would I go about only running code once the callback is complete?

Comment: *"How would I go about only running code once the callback is complete?"* By putting the code inside the callback?

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `console.log()` into the "done" callback function because you can't know exactly when or if it will complete. This is the point of the "done" callback function - - to defer work that needs to be done after a successful call has been made.

JavaScript promises (or JQuery deferreds) could also be used to disconnect the callback(s) from the initial AJAX request for more flexibility, but the nature of AJAX stays the same.

```
$.get("./whazzup.txt", function(text) {
  // This function will only be executed when the AJAX call has successfully completed
  msg = text;
  console.log(msg);
});

// This one was working, because you are basically telling the JavaScript
// runtime to wait 3 seconds (at least) before writing the message and by
// that time the AJAX call has completed. But, this technique is not
// reliable because there may be times when the AJAX call hasn't completed
// after 3 seconds. You just can't know how long it will take.
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(msg); }, 3000);
```

Comment: C'mon Scott, you know this question has been asked many time before...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan but but but, easy rep!